# Get filtered values from array like values between range 10-20

Tags: php

how to get **filtered values** from array like values between range 10-20.
my array contain 10,15,18,25,88,20.
i want to print only between range 10-20.

Answer (score 11):

use  [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) with  [`range`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
$input = array(10,15,18,25,88,20);
$myrange = range(10,20);
$output = array_intersect($input , $myrange );
print_r($output );
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/nm8La)**

Comment: That's REALLY good one. +1. I'd suggest @sachin to use this solution. Wasn't to savvy myself to approach the same since too used to `array_filter` and `create_function`

Comment: Works good. But its a lot of times slower than the approach with array_filter()

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
function range10_20($var) {
    return ( $var >= 10 && $var <= 20 );
}

$input  = array(10,15,18,25,88,20);
$output = array_filter($input, 'range10_20');
```

Or something like that:

```
$input  = array(10,15,18,25,88,20);
$range  = array(
    'from' => 10,
    'to'   => 20
);
$output = array_filter($input, function ($element) use ($range) {
    return ( $var >= $range['from'] && $var <= $range['to'] );
});
```

Comment: Simple solution. If PVP_VERSION > 5.3, you could have used a closure.

Comment: Great one. Exactly what I'm looking for. Furthermore it just needs 15% of time instead of using the approach with range() and intersect() which is really slow!

Comment: @dk1 I was wondering about performance, especially since I was going to be doing timestamps within a one month range. With 2.6 million seconds in a month, the range solution seemed like it might be slow. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: When you have a large range this is the way to go. I used the second solution presented here by @hsz, so that I could define a dynamic range, but had to fix a couple things: (1) $var needs to be $element and (2) I had to include an array_values($output) to remove the keys.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of way to filter array in PHP.

Using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$your_array = array(10,15,18,25,88,20);
$filtered = array_filter($your_array, create_function('$var', 'return $var >= 10 && $var <= 20;'));
var_export($filtered);
```

[In action](http://ideone.com/HIJ4L)

If you want to change range start and range end without modifying create_function code:

```
$your_array = array(10,15,18,25,88,20);
$range_start = 10;
$range_end = 20;
$filtered = array_filter($your_array, create_function('$var', 'return $var >= '.$range_start.' && $var <= '.$range_end.';'));
var_export($filtered);
```

[In action](http://ideone.com/nxtwB)

$your_array = array(10,15,18,25,88,20);

Using foreach loop:

```
$filtered = array();
$range_start = 10;
$range_end = 20;
foreach ($your_array as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v >= $range_start && $v <= $range_end) {
        $filtered[$k] = $v;
    }
}
var_export($filtered);
```

[In action](http://ideone.com/nvl1X)

Or so if you don't need to create new array, but modify existing one:

```
$your_array = array(10,15,18,25,88,20);

$range_start = 10;
$range_end = 20;
foreach ($your_array as $k=>$v) {
        if (!($v >= $range_start && $v <= $range_end)) {
                unset($your_array[$k]);
        }
}
var_export($your_array);
```

[In action](http://ideone.com/S3laS)

Answer (score 0):

Any specific requirement? 
php standard array does not support range search.

I have 2 suggestions:
1) sort the array and then search for the your upper limit, anything before the upperlimit would be your results
2) traverse the array, while traversing, apply your range conditions.