# PHP array read out succession

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP I have an Array like this:

`$BulkArray[$i]`

This Array is feed with plenty of Numbers (e.g. 1 => 100, 2  => 300, 3  => 100, and so on).
Now I want to find within the whole range of numbers, the greatest succession of a number equal or less than 500. I want to write the number of succession.

for example I have the array

```
1 => 100, 2  => 300, 3  => 100, 
4  => 50, 5 => 50, 6  => 50, 7  => 50, 8  => 50, 
9  => 500, 10  => 200, 11  => 100
```

as you can see, number 1,2 & 3 are together 500. So this is the first succession.

2,3,4,5 are also 500 together. (This succession(4) is bigger than the first succession(3))

And so on,then you will get the highest succession: 3,4,5,6,7,8 (succession with 6 numbers) which is 350 (but lower than 500m, as we searched for it)

Now, how can I write with the Array: 
`$BulkArray[$i]`, that the highest succession is 6 ?

Because 6 is the highest succession found in the whole array for 500!

(It's for categorizing specific Carparts)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174760/get-filtered-values-from-array-like-values-between-range-10-20

Comment: You would likely have to calculate all permutations of the array that add up to <= your limit. Then take the one with the most numbers.

Comment: Actually if you are looking for just the longest streak, sort by the numbers so smallest is first and just start adding them up until the sum is >= your limit. The count of numbers you got through is your answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Click Here](http://3v4l.org/0okDT) or [here](http://codepad.org/dIuT3N0z) you can see somehing

```js
<?php //lets  call your $BulkArray = $values;
$values=array( 1 => 100, 2  => 300, 3  => 100, 
4  => 50, 5 => 50, 6  => 50, 7  => 50, 8  => 50, 
9  => 500, 10  => 200, 11  => 100 );
$sum=0; // to sum up until 500
$Vals500=array(); // array to store index with <= 500
$i=0;  // index for new aaray that will store keys that made up <= 500
$key1=1; //value to iterate the array defined above
//print_r($values); echo '<br/>';

for($key=1; $key <= count($values); $key++){

$sum = $sum + $values[$key]; // get sum of values

if($sum <= 500){ $Vals500[$i][]=$key; } //append all key of sum ==500
   
 if($sum == 500) { $i++;  $key=$key1++; $sum=0; } //check sum then reinitialize values
 
}
foreach($Vals500 as $val){} //search for second array with many indeces in $Vals500. NB: i fail this place
echo print_r($Vals500); 

print 'the highest succession found is  '; print_r($Vals500[2]); //
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of User "fas M" here again, with little improvement:

```
<?php //lets  call your $BulkArray = $values;
 $values=array( 1 => 100, 2  => 300, 3  => 100, 
4  => 50, 5 => 50, 6  => 50, 7  => 50, 8  => 50, 
9  => 500, 10  => 200, 11  => 100 );
$sum=0; // to sum up until 500
$Vals500=array(); // array to store index with <= 500
$i=0; // index for new aaray that will store keys that made up <= 500
$key1=1; //value to iterate the array defined above

for($key=1; $key <= count($values); $key++){

$sum = $sum + $values[$key]; // get sum of values

if($sum <= 500){ $Vals500[$i][]=$key; } //append all key of sum ==500

    if($sum >= 500) { $i++;  $key=$key1++; $sum=0; } //check sum then reintialize
    //added bigger equal

}

echo count(max($Vals500)); // read out the biggest succession
?>
```

Thanks again to fas M !