# PHP select a range from an array()

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array() of years, they are in order lowest to highest, they are not sequential, so 1100, 1295, 1733,1734, 1980 etc. The key starts at 0 up to the number of years. So [0] => 1100, [1] => 1295.. [5] => 1980. What i am trying to do is pull a range out from the middle, so a user inputs start year = 1200 and end year = 1900. Can anyone help me create a new array from my original array with values that are between the start and end years. Thanks for your help. I am using PHP version 5.6+ cant remember the exact version.

Comment: Have a look at the `array_search()` function to identify your start and end keys, and then at `array_slice()` to extract the range if the user inputs exact values from your array; or even `array_filter()` to extract the values between start and end dates

Comment: do you have every year in your array, or only some years?

Comment: rtfm only some, not sequential.   Mark Baker; ok I see where your going with that, like searching a string gettng the length then doing a string length on it..... hmmm

Comment: No, that is not what Mark said, but that is also a possibility. Implode, regex/strpos, explode

Comment: array_filter() has lead me to this stackoverflow question which looks promising. Dont want to waste anyone elses time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174760/get-filtered-values-from-array-like-values-between-range-10-20

Comment: Thats a good find Chris! A very smart way to use array_intersect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a custom callback is the shortest way to get the time span:

```
$array = [1100, 1295, 1733, 1734, 1980];
$start = 1200;
$end = 1733;
$result = array_filter($array, function ($value) use ($start, $end) 
  {return $start <= $value && $value <= $end;});
var_dump($result);
```

But there are many other ways.

Comment: Yes, I am checking it out on my server, cheers ;) Building a timeline of historic caving events.. Bring on the darkness!